# Why does my script fail on the first attempt at running the OOBE (but work on the second)?

Tags: powershell, windows-10-v1803

I have a script that uses C# code in powershell to set the screen resolution and orientation for the devices I'm developing a windows image for.

For various reasons, related to screen orientation mostly, I am choosing not to use the  settings in my unattend.xml.

After installing the image on any of the target devices, when I boot the device and let the OOBE complete using my unattend.xml answer file, the script I have runs, but returns a result indicating that it failed to process my request.

If I then take the finished unit and run sysprep on it to set it to run the OOBE again, the script succeeds on the second run.

Why would this be?

Here is the code for the powershell/C# script.

```cs
using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

namespace Resolution 
{ 

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
    public struct DEVMODE 
    { 
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst=32)]
       public string dmDeviceName;

       public short  dmSpecVersion;
       public short  dmDriverVersion;
       public short  dmSize;
       public short  dmDriverExtra;
       public int    dmFields;
       public int    dmPositionX;
       public int    dmPositionY;
       public int    dmDisplayOrientation;
       public int    dmDisplayFixedOutput;
       public short  dmColor;
       public short  dmDuplex;
       public short  dmYResolution;
       public short  dmTTOption;
       public short  dmCollate;

       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
       public string dmFormName;

       public short  dmLogPixels;
       public short  dmBitsPerPel;
       public int    dmPelsWidth;
       public int    dmPelsHeight;
       public int    dmDisplayFlags;
       public int    dmDisplayFrequency;
       public int    dmICMMethod;
       public int    dmICMIntent;
       public int    dmMediaType;
       public int    dmDitherType;
       public int    dmReserved1;
       public int    dmReserved2;
       public int    dmPanningWidth;
       public int    dmPanningHeight;
    }; 

    class NativeMethods 
    { 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        public static extern int EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DEVMODE devMode); 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        public static extern int ChangeDisplaySettings(ref DEVMODE devMode, int flags); 

        public const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1; 
        public const int CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY = 0x01; 
        public const int CDS_TEST = 0x02; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL = 0; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_RESTART = 1; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_FAILED = -1;
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE = -2;
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_NOTUPDATED = -3;
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_BADFLAGS = -4;
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM = -5;
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_BADDUALVIEW = -6;
        public const int DMDO_DEFAULT = 0;
        public const int DMDO_90 = 1;
        public const int DMDO_180 = 2;
        public const int DMDO_270 = 3;
    } 



    public class PrmaryScreenResolution 
    { 
        static public string SetDevAResolution() //Landscape oriented device
        {
            return ChangeResolution(1024, 768, NativeMethods.DMDO_DEFAULT);
        }

        static public string SetDevBResolution() //High resolution portrait device
        {
            return ChangeResolution(800, 1280, NativeMethods.DMDO_90);
        }

        static public string SetDevCResolution() //Portrait oriented device
        {
            return ChangeResolution(768, 1024, NativeMethods.DMDO_90);
        }

        static public string ChangeResolution(int width, int height, int orientation) 
        { 

            DEVMODE dm = GetDevMode(); 

            if (0 != NativeMethods.EnumDisplaySettings(null, NativeMethods.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm)) 
            {

                // Set Width and heigh
                dm.dmPelsHeight = height;
                dm.dmPelsWidth = width;
                //dm.dmLogPixels = 96;

                dm.dmDisplayOrientation = orientation;

                int iRet = NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, NativeMethods.CDS_TEST); 

                if (iRet == NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_FAILED) 
                { 
                    return "Unable To Process Your Request. Sorry For This Inconvenience."; 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    iRet = NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, NativeMethods.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY); 
                    switch (iRet) 
                    { 
                        case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL: 
                            { 
                                return "Success"; 
                            } 
                        case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_RESTART: 
                            { 
                                return "You Need To Reboot For The Change To Happen.\n If You Feel Any Problem After Rebooting Your Machine\nThen Try To Change Resolution In Safe Mode."; 
                            }
                        case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_FAILED:
                            {
                                return "Display change failed.";
                            }
                        case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE:
                            {
                                return "Bad Mode";
                            }
                        case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_NOTUPDATED:
                            {
                                return "Display not updated.";
                            }
                        case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_BADFLAGS:
                            {
                                return "Bad Flags";
                            }
                        case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM:
                            {
                                return "Bad Parameter";
                            }
                        case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_BADDUALVIEW:
                            {
                                return "Bad Dual View";
                            }
                        default: 
                            { 
                                return "Failed To Change The Resolution (B)"; 
                            } 
                    } 

                } 


            } 
            else 
            { 
                return "Failed To Change The Resolution. (A)"; 
            } 
        } 

        private static DEVMODE GetDevMode() 
        { 
            DEVMODE dm = new DEVMODE(); 
            dm.dmDeviceName = new String(new char[32]); 
            dm.dmFormName = new String(new char[32]); 
            dm.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(dm); 
            return dm; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The first time the script runs (during OOBE attempt 1) I execute one of the SetDev*Resolution() functions, and the "ChangeResolution()" function returns: "Unable To Process Your Request. Sorry For This Inconvenience." This tells me that when I attempted to call "ChangeDisplaySettings()" It failed.

Could it have something to do with there not being a user when this script is run? If that is the case, is there a workaround, or do I need to figure out another method?

Comment: Yes, it will most likely have to do with no users being loaded at the time, as there would be no active desktop to apply settings to.  Which section/pass of the Unattend.xml are you running the script in, and what method are you using to launch it during the unattended setup?  Why not just use the in-built Display settings for the OOBE pass (7) of the Unattend.xml?

Comment: I'm running it in the OOBE pass as a part of my OEM_OOBE.ps1 script. I'm not using the in-built display settings because they have issues if the locale changes (I'm not actually changing the locale, but I've had issues anyway, so I decided to just try this method. Also the in-built settings don't let me set the screen orientation or automatically select the resolution based on what device I'm on.)

Comment: I should also share that I'm running the OEM_OOBE.ps1 script as a synchronous first logon command in the OOBE pass (7).

Comment: It could be because you are running it using the synchronous first login command. Windows 10 no longer runs them synchronously. You need to modify the registry to enforce synchronous execution. I’ve had some issues in the past as well and new versions of MDT account for this in the task sequence.  This references the change but I can’t find the registry tweak off hand: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-firstlogoncommands